# Display text at the top of bar and change x axis text color in d3

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I have a d3 bar chart which will display tooltip on hover. Now I need an extra functionality to display the value text on top of the bar and change the x-axis label color when a bar is clicked. Any idea why it's not getting displayed? And how to change x-axis label color for that particular bar?

```
var width = 400, height = 350;
    var margin = {top: 90, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 80};

    //data
    var data = [ {"month":"JAN","patients":120}, {"month":"FEB","patients":50}, {"month":"MAR","patients":80}, {"month":"APR","patients":20}, {"month":"MAY","patients":100}, {"month":"JUN","patients":350}];

    //x and y Scales
    var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

    xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.month; }));
    yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.patients; })]);

    //x and y Axes
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .outerTickSize(0);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left");


    var tip = d3.tip()
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
    .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(function(d) {
        return "<span class='tooltip-line'>One: " + d.patients + "</span><span>Two: " + d.patients + "</span>";
    });

    //create svg container
    var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");        

    // tooltip
    svg.call(tip);

    // Horizontal grid
    svg.append("g")         
    .attr("class", "grid horizontal")
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale)
          .orient("left")
          .tickSize(-(height + margin.top + margin.bottom - 70), 0, 0)
          .tickFormat("")
          );

    //create bars
    svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.month); })
    .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.patients); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - yScale(d.patients); })
    .on("click", function(d) {
        // add text on top of bar
        d3.select(this).append("text")
          .attr("x",  xScale.rangeBand() / 2 )
          .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.patients) + 5 ; })
          .attr("dy", "1em")
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("font-size", "14px")
          .attr("fill", "orange")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0, -20)"; })
          .text(function(d) { return d.patients; });
    })
    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide)


    //drawing the x axis on svg
    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

    //drawing the y axis on svg
    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end");

    svg.selectAll(".tick")
    .filter(function (d) { return d === 0;     
    }).remove();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7E2L5/7/)

Comment: *"Any idea why it's not getting displayed?"* As the two answers stated, you cannot append a text element to a rect element. Here is a explanation in S.O. Docs: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/d3.js/2537/core-svg-concepts-used-in-d3-js-visualization/17339/correctly-appending-an-svg-element#t=201702240014565450387.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot append a 'text' element to a 'rect' element, so I fixed it by wrapping each bar in a 'g' element. Append the text to each bar with opacity at 0, then in your click handler, select the 'nextSibling' (which will be your invisible text element) and set the appropriate opacity. Like so:

```
//create bars
var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("g");

bars.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.month); })
  .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.patients); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - yScale(d.patients); })
  .on("click", function(d) {
    var txt = d3.select(this.nextSibling);

    if(txt.attr('opacity') === '0') {
      txt.attr('opacity', '1');
    } else {
      txt.attr('opacity', '0');
    }

  });

bars.append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.month); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.patients) + 2 ; })
  .attr("dy", "1em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-size", "16px")
  .attr("fill", "orange")
  .attr("opacity", '0')
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(20, -20)"; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.patients; });
```

[And here's the fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/1n19wr8h/10/)

Comment: Thanks, how to change the x axis label color for the selected bar?

Comment: .attr("fill", "orange")

Answer (score 0):

Your appending the "text" element inside the "rect" element. i.e. `<rect><text></text></rect>`. What you want is svg that looks more like `<rect></rect><text></text>`